# can I quickly clean up html files with emacs (prelude)

Tags: html, whitespace, prelude

How do you clean up an html file?

For example, this file has one too many empty line between the div tags.
I would like cleanup to leave only one blank line there.

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div>
      foo
    </div>


    <div>
      abc
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

What I tried in my emacs prelude

```
M-x help
d PATTERN   Show a list of functions, variables, and other items whose
              documentation matches the PATTERN (a list of words or a regexp).
entered 'clean html'
```

> Nothing found

Comment: You may want to read [`(emacs) Blank Lines`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Blank-Lines.html), particularly about the command `delete-blank-lines`, which is globally bound to `C-x C-o` by default.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use `query-regexp-replace` (bound by default to `C-M-%`)
to substitute three or more consecutive newlines with two newlines.
You need to know how to add a newline to your query and replacement
strings: `C-q C-j`. Altogether you'd type:

`C-M-% C-q C-j \{3,\} RET C-q C-j C-q C-j RET !`

Answer (score 0):

```
(defun just-one-empty-line (&optional beg end)
  "Delete consecutive empty lines, retain just one.

Works on region if active.
Accepts optional arguments BEG END to specify a region"
  (interactive "*")
  (let ((beg (cond (beg)
           ((region-active-p)
            (region-beginning))
           (t (point-min))))
    (end (cond (end (copy-marker end))
           ((region-active-p)
            (copy-marker (region-end)))
           (t (copy-marker (point-max))))))
    (save-excursion
      (save-restriction
        (narrow-to-region beg end)
        (goto-char beg)
        (while (not (eobp))
          (while (looking-at "^\\([ \t]*\n\\)[ \t]*$")
            (delete-region (match-beginning 1) (match-end 1)))
          (forward-line 1))
    (widen)))))
```